# pyspark: SQL count() fails

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe that looks something like this

```
x  |count
1  |3
3  |5
4  |3
```

Below is my spark code:

```
sdf.createOrReplaceTempView('sdf_view')
spark.sql('SELECT MAX(count), x FROM sdf_view')
```

This seems like a perfect SQL query and I'm wondering why this doesn't work with Spark. What I want to find is the maximum count along with the x corresponding to it. 
Any leads appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is:

```
AnalysisException: u"grouping expressions sequence is empty, and 'sdf_view.`x`' is not an aggregate function. Wrap '(max(sdf_view.`count`) AS `max(count)`)' in windowing function(s) or wrap 'sdf_view.`x`' in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.
```

I added another row:

```
x = [{"x": 1, "count": 3}, {"x": 3, "count": 5}, {"x": 4, "count": 3}, {"x": 4, "count": 60}]
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(x)

+-----+---+
|count|  x|
+-----+---+
|    3|  1|
|    5|  3|
|    3|  4|
|   60|  4|
+-----+---+
```

Your SQL statement is odd and you need to say how you want to group things. I'm guessing you want to group the X's and get the max of each of the unique X's? In other words, do you want a max count for each of the unique X's?

```
y = spark.sql('SELECT MAX(count), x FROM sdf_view GROUP BY x ')
y.show()

+----------+---+
|max(count)|  x|
+----------+---+
|         3|  1|
|         5|  3|
|        60|  4|
+----------+---+
```

Or Do you want to just find the highest count of them all?

```
y = spark.sql('SELECT MAX(count) FROM sdf_view')
y.show()

+----------+
|max(count)|
+----------+
|        60|
+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. But what I want to find the maximum count, along with the corresponding x. I should have clarified this in my question. Updating it now.

Comment: Ordering it by descending order and taking the top one worked! y = spark.sql('SELECT MAX(count), x FROM sdf_view GROUP BY x ORDER BY max(count) DESC').show(1)